# Pass C# ASP.NET array to Javascript array

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Does anyone know how to pass a C# ASP.NET array to a JavaScript array? Sample code will also be nice.

Sorry if I was vague earlier guys. The question is actually quite simple. Let's say for simplicity that in my `aspx.cs` file I declare:

```
int [] numbers = new int[5];
```

Now I want to pass `numbers` to the client side and use the data in the array within JavaScript . How would I do this?

Comment: Are you talking about serializing to JSON?

Comment: I think we need more details here. Do you want to pass if from the code-behind to the aspx or do you want to use AJAX to send an array of data to javascript... or something entirely different?

Comment: please see above. sorry for being too vague.

Comment: possible duplicate of [assign C# string of array or string\[\] to javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023972/assign-c-sharp-string-of-array-or-string-to-javascript-array)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript to inject javascript into the page on Page_Load.

Here's a link to MSDN reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Here's the code in Page_Load:

```
  List<string> tempString = new List<string>();
  tempString.Add("Hello");
  tempString.Add("World");

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("<script>");
  sb.Append("var testArray = new Array;");
  foreach(string str in tempString)
  {
    sb.Append("testArray.push('" + str + "');");
  }
  sb.Append("</script>");

  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "TestArrayScript", sb.ToString());
```

Notes: Use StringBuilder to build the script string as it will probably be long.

And here's the Javascript that checks for the injected array "testArray" before you can  work with it:

```
if (testArray)
{
  // do something with testArray
}
```

There's 2 problems here:

1. Some consider this intrusive for C# to inject Javascript
2. We'll have to declare the array at a global context

If you can't live with that, another way would be to have the C# code save the Array into View State, then have the JavaScript use PageMethods (or web services) to call back to the server to get that View State object as an array.  But I think that may be overkill for something like this.

Comment: I'll take a look thanks for the explanation. One thing, which array are you referring to as global and why?

Comment: @Gary: My concern here is the ad hoc serialization. If the strings in that list were to contain single quotes, we'd have a problem. That's why using the JSON serializer is safer.

Comment: @cfarm54: The "this" is the `Page`. Using `RegisterStartupScript` is a good idea.

Comment: @cfarm54: If you look at where we have to declare the testArray array, it is a global variable in Javascript.

And yes, "this" refers to the Page in this case.  If you put this in a User Control, it will return the User Control type; registering the code to the control rather than the page.

Comment: @Steven: That is true.  I think this solution is a "quick fix" and it is good enough as the scope of object that we're passing is small.  If we were to pass bigger objects then JSON serialization would be the way to go.

Comment: thanks guys that makes a lot of sense. the actual problem is that I'm calling a webservice in the .cs file which returns an array of doubles. If I then push this into javascript (where I can use a nice google scatter plot), would this interfere with the other components on the page if I was using js for those also? I'm assuming that it'd only affect it if I were to declare another js array with the same name...

Comment: @cfarm54: It should not affect other scripts.  It's equivalent of having multiple <script> sections or multiple .js files on your page.  If you do call RegisterClientScript multiple times, please ensure that the second parameter ("TestArrayScript" in this case) is unique to the other RegisterClientScript's.

If my answer is helpful, please rate up / mark answer!  I'm trying to get enough points to put comments :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are helping a lot. I'm also new to stack overflow, how do I rate up?

Comment: @Gary: My concern here is correctness, not size. Since the OP is using doubles and converting them, there doesn't seem to be any risk of injection, however.

Answer (score 58):

serialize it with `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` class and assign to javascript var

dummy sample:

```
<% var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); %>
var jsVariable = <%= serializer.Serialize(array) %>;
```

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity. please see above.

Comment: @zerkms could you explain what's going on? sorry i'm noob at this

Comment: @zerkms - consider editing this answer to make it complete and highlight the fact it supports arbitrary types?

Answer (score 18):

This is to supplement zerkms's answer.

To pass data across language barriers, you would need a way to represent the data as a string by serializing the data. One of the serialization methods for JavaScript is JSON. In zerkms's example, the code would be placed inside of an aspx page. To combine his example and yours together on one aspx page, you would have,

```
<%
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    // Fill up numbers...

    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
%>
```

somewhere later on the aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsVariable = <%= serializer.Serialize(numbers) %>;
</script>
```

This answer though, assumes that you are generating JavaScript from the initial page load. As per the comments in your post, this could have been done via AJAX. In that case, you would have the server respond with the result of the serialization and then deserialize it in JavaScript using your favorite framework.

Note: Also do not mark this as an answer since I wanted the syntax highlighting to make another answer more clear.

Comment: do you mean:

var jsVariable = <%=serializer.Serialize(numbers)%>

?

Comment: also, what do you mean generatign js from the initial page load?

Comment: No, because you are in the context of generating JavaScript. When you have int[] numbers = new int[5] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, serializing it gives you, "[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]". So the generated javascript becomes "var jsVariable = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];"

Comment: Correction, you are right, serializer.Serialize(numbers) with the semicolon. I misread and thought you meant the semicolon. I've also made the correction to the code.

Comment: for some reason this isn't working. int[] is on the backend (aspx.cs file) and I also declare the serializer in the cs file. when i write out the script tag I get the error that int[] doesn't exist within the current context

Answer (score 11):

In the page file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = eval('[<% =string.Join(", ", numbers) %>]');
</script>
```

while in code behind:

```
public int[] numbers = WhatEverGetTheArray();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the answer here...can you walk me through it?

Comment: @cfarm54-In code behind, you initialize the int[] called numbers. And then in the javascript, `string.Join(", ", numbers)` make the "numbers" array to be a string like "1,2,3,4". After that, we use `eval('[1,2,3,4]')` to convert an array-like string to an array.

Comment: The variable "a" will be the exact js array. You can use any array operation to it e.g. a[0] a[1] a.length.

Answer (score 9):

For array of objects:

```
var array= JSON.parse('@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(numbers)'.replace(/&quot;/g, "\""));
```

For array of int:

```
 var array= JSON.parse('@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(numbers)');
```

Answer (score 4):

Prepare an array (in my case it is 2d array):

```
        // prepare a 2d array in c#
        ArrayList header = new ArrayList { "Task Name", "Hours"};
        ArrayList data1 = new ArrayList {"Work", 2};
        ArrayList data2 = new ArrayList { "Eat", 2 };
        ArrayList data3 = new ArrayList { "Sleep", 2 };
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList {header, data1, data2, data3};
        // convert it in json
        string dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None);
        // store it in viewdata/ viewbag
        ViewBag.Data = new HtmlString(dataStr);
```

Parse it in the view.

```
<script>    
    var data = JSON.parse('@ViewBag.Data');
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

In your case you can directly use variable name instead of ViewBag.Data.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this similar situation and I resolved it quiet easily.Here is what I did. Assuming you already have the value in array at your `aspx.cs` page.

1)Put a hidden field in your aspx page and us the hidden field ID to store the array value.

```
 HiddenField2.Value = string.Join(",", myarray);
```

2)Now that the hidden field has the value stored, just separated by commas. Use this hidden field in JavaScript like this. Simply create an array in JavaScript and then store the value in that array by removing the commas.

```
var hiddenfield2 = new Array();
hiddenfield2=document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField2.ClientID%>').value.split(',');
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, with all the new MVC and other technologies I forgot about this classic :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative solution. You can use ClientScriptManager Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration. Here is an example for chart data.

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

_data = "[Date.UTC(2018, 9, 29, 0, 3), parseFloat(21.84)]
         ,[Date.UTC(2018, 9, 29, 0, 13), parseFloat(21.84)]
         ,[Date.UTC(2018, 9, 29, 0, 23), parseFloat(21.83)]
         ,[Date.UTC(2018, 9, 29, 0, 33), parseFloat(21.83)]";
page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("chartdata0", _data);
```

This code creates an array on the client side

```
var chartdata0 = new Array([Date.UTC(2018, 9, 29, 0, 3), parseFloat(21.84)]
             ,[Date.UTC(2018, 9, 29, 0, 13), parseFloat(21.84)]
             ,[Date.UTC(2018, 9, 29, 0, 23), parseFloat(21.83)]
             ,[Date.UTC(2018, 9, 29, 0, 33), parseFloat(21.83)]);
```

See the following article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration?view=netframework-4.8

This solution has an issue with bigger arrays on chrome 64 browser including "Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)". You may get "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". However it is working with IE11, Microsoft Edge, and FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple

The array of integers is quite simple to pass. However this solution works for more complex data as well. In your **model**:

```
public int[] Numbers => new int[5];
```

In your **view**:

```
numbers = @(new HtmlString(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.Numbers)))
```

### Optional

A tip for passing strings. You may want JSON encoder to not escape some symbols in your strings. In this example I want raw unescaped cyrillic letters. In your **view**:

```
strings = @(
new HtmlString(
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.Strings, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(
            UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin,
            UnicodeRanges.Cyrillic)
    })))
```