# assign C# string of array or string[] to javascript array

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a js code in which an array works well when its like

```
var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C"
                     ];
```

I then made an array string in my code behind or .cs like on class level

```
 public static string[] test={"animal","lovely"};
```

I then changed js array to this

```
 var availableTags =  "<%=test%>"; // also tried without quotes
```

Now I m not having the results as was having with previous js array

**Editing with complete code,the jquery I taken from http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple**

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class onecol : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   JavaScriptSerializer serializer;

   public static string test = "['animal','lovely']";
    public static string check;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //serializer
        this.detail.ToolsFile = "BasicTools.xml";
        test = returnTitle();
    }

}
```

and the script with html is

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jscript.js"></script>  
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css"></script>  
     <link href="~/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
                var availableTags =  <%=test%>;

              function split(val) {
                  return val.split(/,\s*/);
              }
              function extractLast(term) {
                  return split(term).pop();
              }

              $("#tags")
              // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            .bind("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
                },
                focus: function () {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push(ui.item.value);
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push("");
                    this.value = terms.join(", ");
                    return false;
                }
            });
          });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<div class="demo" >
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
    <input id="Text1" class="#tags" size="50" />


</div>
</div>
```

actually its a auto complete functionality to give tags ,the auto complete suggestions for tagging I want to get from C# code ,I took Jquery source from jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple and then I tried to give it C# string from .cs file , I explained it with code on edited version , with C# code behind it works exactly as its in the link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass C# ASP.NET array to Javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464498/pass-c-sharp-asp-net-array-to-javascript-array)

Comment: @TimSchmelter edited ,please check

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to serialize the C# string array into a javascript array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Usually I create a simple static class as a wrapper.

```
public static class JavaScript
{
    public static string Serialize(object o)
    {            
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(o);
    }
}
```

Then you can use that class to serialize the item you need to

```
//C# Array(Member of asp page)
protected string[] Values = { "Sweet", "Awesome", "Cool" };

<script type="text/javascript">
    var testArray = <%=JavaScript.Serialize(this.Values) %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var availableTags =  ['<%=String.join("','",test)%>'];
```

Comment: It should be noted that if any of your strings contain a single quote, these should be escaped.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'String' does not contain a definition for 'join'

Comment: @user1074474 It was giving me the same error.  Were you doing an online coding challenge?  I think that some commands aren't allowed in some of those, unless I'm missing something.  In order to do a workaround, I just created a StringBuilder and iterated over the array, adding integer values, then parsing a string from the result.

Answer (score 3):

It would be something like this...

```
var availableTags =  ["<%= string.Join("\", \"", test) %>"];
```

or

```
var availableTags =  ['<%= string.Join("', '", test) %>'];
```

The first one would render as

```
var availableTags = ["Sweet", "Awesome", "Cool"];
```

and the second one would render as

```
var availableTags = ['Sweet', 'Awesome', 'Cool'];
```

both of which are fine for autocomplete.

Comment: I tried it with/without quotes/[] and with ' ' as well , but still not working

Comment: @user1074474, What do you mean by "not working"? Show us the error or the rendered HTML (do view source).

Comment: @user1074474, We don't have to see the full source code. All we need to see is the error if you are getting or relevant portion of rendered HTML.

Comment: actually its a auto complete functionality to give tags ,the auto complete suggestions for tagging I want to get from C# code ,I took Jquery source from http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple  and then I tried to give it C# string from .cs file , I explained it with code on edited version , with C# code behind it works exactly as its in the link

Comment: Do view source in your browser and search for var availableTags =  <What Is Rendered Here?>;

Comment: ASP.NET would not send <%=test%> to the browser. It would be different.

Comment: you are right , i got   var availableTags =  "['animal','usman lovely']";
in the source , so should i need to get it as "["animal","usman lovely"]" because original source has written it as it is ,hows that possible in C# ?

Comment: I need my C# code to give C# code string like present here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple  , please let me know  a method

Comment: There are no quotes before and after the [ and ] in the code posted here. Use the exact code given here and you would get exactly what is needed.

Comment: yes I know , I did with and without  "" but still its the same

Comment: I did this  public static string test = "'animal','lovely'";  even then I dont get the required string in view source(html render) , please tell me how to formulate the C# string so that it become exactly as in link

Comment: There could be other things to why the autocomplete is not working but the code would render proper script as needed by jQuryUI as part of the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`test` property should be a string property and it should render the string which will be parsed by Js engine as an array. Try this.

Code behind property

```
public static string test= "['animal','usman lovely']";
```

JS

```
 var availableTags =  <%=test%>;//No quotes
```

Comment: Should probably drop the curly braces and define it as `string`.

Comment: What do you see in the source when the page is rendered?

Comment: you are right , i got var availableTags = "['animal','usman lovely']"; in the source , so should i need to get it as "["animal","usman lovely"]" because original source has written it as it is ,hows that possible in C# ?I need my C# code to give C# code string like present here jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple , please let me know a method

Comment: Remove the double qutoes arount `text` i.e. `var availableTags =  <%=test%>`. Then you can use that variable as an array in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

only use indexes to get your test string array 
i have tried by giving indexes like

```
var availableTags =  "<%=test[0]%>";  // animal 
var availableTags =  "<%=test[1]%>";  // lovely
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing an online coding challenge, the browser-based IDE might not let you use string.join, like with my job, which has us use iMocha.

Instead of that, I just created a StringBuilder object (from System.Text) and iterated over the array, appending each integer and a blank space, then converting the result to a string.  Something like this:

```
var array = new int[] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
var str = new StringBuilder();
foreach (int i in array)
{
  str.Append(i);
  str.Append(" ");
}
var result = str.ToString();
```