# Adding a pushpin to a bing map view in ASP.net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, bing-maps

I am building a asp.net MVC 3 application. I have a SQL Server database where my data is stored and i am using the schema first model from entity framework. I know how to get my data from the database but while i am still fairly new to MVC i do not know who to add pushpins to the map from coordinates stored in my database. Can anyone assist me by showing an example.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you planning to do this with the Ajax 7.0 ?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427604.aspx

Comment: Yes I am. Any experience using it? well any version of Ajax that I am able to accomplish the task with is pretty much good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need some server-side code to load your pin data into from SqlServer.

in your c# code behind, you can populate some pin latitude / longitude variables in the `Page_Load` to pass over to use on your javacsript side.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string[] pinLat;
    protected string[] pinLong;

    public static class JavaScript
    {
        public static string Serialize(object o)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return js.Serialize(o);
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Populate your latiude and longitude from SQL Server into our arrays to be used in javascript
        pinLat = new string[3] { "55.342575", "15.342575", "25.342575" };
        pinLong = new string[3] { "-55.342570", "-55.342570", "-55.342570" };
    }
}
```

Use JavaScript.Serialize, kindly provided by [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023972/assign-c-sharp-string-of-array-or-string-to-javascript-array) to convert the c# array to a javascript array, and loop through each and pin them to the map.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    // Serialize our c# array into javascript array
    var pinLatitude = <%=JavaScript.Serialize(this.pinLat) %>;
    var pinLogitude = <%=JavaScript.Serialize(this.pinLong) %>;


      function loadPins() {
              try {
                  for (var i = 0; i < pinLatitude.length; i++) {

                      var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(pinLatitude[i], pinLogitude[i]),{ draggable: true });
                      pushpin.setOptions({ visible: true });
                      map.entities.push(pushpin);

                  }
              }
              catch (err) {
                alert(err)
              }
          }

     function GetMap() {
              // Initialize the map
              try {
                  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), { credentials: 'heyhey', mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road });
                  loadPins();
              }
              catch (err) {
                  alert(err.message);
              }
          }


</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <body onload="GetMap();">
         <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:750px; height:500px;"></div>
    </body>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: @OrvillePatterson Anytime!