# How do I implement autocomplete textbox where values come from the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have an application which will hold a number of datasets. I want to create a text box with autocomplete matching the dataset title. Initially I used [jQuery's autocomplete widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) searching the database and that worked. However, it was too slow and database intensive.

I am now trying to implement it by grabbing the list of titles when I build the model and using that for the autocomplete. However I can't get it working.

In my model I have

```
public IEnumerable<string> DatasetTitles { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SearchFreeText)
```

and

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SearchFreeText').autocomplete({
        source: '@Model.DatasetTitles.ToArray()'
    });
});
```

This fails with a 404 error as it tries to fetch data from the location 'System.String[]'. This is probably because the widget expects a URL when given a string.

Next I tried removing the single quotes so it would treat it as an array rather than a string.

```
source: @Model.DatasetTitles.ToArray()
```

but this gives a syntax error.

Is there a way to get an autocomplete list of terms from the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your C# array into a valid javascript Array (i.e. `["a","b","c"...]`). There are many ways to do that here is my suggestion:

```
string.Concat("[", string.Join(",", Model.DatasetTitles.Select(s => string.Concat("'", s, "'"))), "]");
```

In essence I am taking each element in the `DatasetTitles` collection and transforming it to a javascript string literal. Then joining those all up with `,` separators and finally putting square brackets around the whole thing.

Not particularly elegant and there are almost certainly better ways to transform the data but hopefully that will get you on the right track.

EDIT: You could also look at the `JavaScriptSerializer` which is the frameworks class for converting C# objects to valid javascript. This is probably perferrable over manually transforming the data as shown above. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9024029/61470

Comment: This works, but there are some additional points worth bearing in mind if anyone else uses this. @Html.Raw is required so the quotes aren't encoded. Also Resharper gives a syntax error for the correct solution, but you can ignore it. @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.DatasetTitles))