# how to display string array values in javascript alert popup

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to display all string values one by one in javascript alert popup. but my code is not working . My code looks like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(x)
    {        
        for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
        {
        alert(x[i]);    
        }        

    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
   <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btn_Click" /> 
    </div>

C# code:


 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string [] str=new string[5];
       str[0] = "string1";
       str[1] = "string2";
       str[2] = "string3";
       str[3] = "string4";
       str[4] = "string5";
       btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:test(str);");

    }
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Write the str variable array in javascript instead of in c# code, javascript could not recognize the str array values.

Comment: It is some what similar to-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464498/pass-c-sharp-asp-net-array-to-javascript-array

Comment: no need for the `javascript:` unless you have client side VBScript in the same page

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the `join` method on an array to merge the elements in the array:

```
function test(x)
{        
    alert(x.join(","));  
}
```

Where above the `,` is the delimiter.

Edit:

It seems you have a .NET array you want to encode to javascript. You can use the `Json` helper as shown below:

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "test(" + System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(str) + ");return false;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "test('"+String.join(",",str)+"'.split(','));");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line 
    btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:test(str);");
str is a string, not a variable.

This should instead be

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:test("+str+");");
```