# filling a JavaScript array with 2D String array from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I'm building some Web Application using aspx and C# and i want to create an 2D String array in the java script but to initialize it with an array from my c# code. I used the "<% ... %> for it but it didn't work. My code is like this:

```
iconColors = new String[,];
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // some code that filling the array
    }
```

in Java Script:

```
<script>
var seatColor = "<%= iconColors %>"; 
for (.... i and j....) {// its a double loop
 document.write("....."+iconColos[i,j]+"...");
}
</script>
```

again, it doesn't work. help somebody?

Comment: Are you saying your seatColor array is empty or the loop isn't working? Ay console errors?

Comment: The loop is not empty. the loop works and but it just doesn't write the array content... In the  console it says its unidentified and the error is 500 - Internal server error

Comment: You can better serialize the 2D Array to JSON & use the JSON in your javascript.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

i guess this must work.

```
<script>
var seatColor = "<%= iconColors %>"; 
for (.... i and j....) {// its a double loop
  document.write("....."+seatColor [i][j]+"...");
}
</script>
```

Comment: @user1857251 You have iconColors, not seatColor in your loop.

Comment: maybe you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464498/pass-c-sharp-asp-net-array-to-javascript-array

Answer (score 0):

There are no native 2D arrays in JavaScript. You need to create your own. I saw someone use this method: `var arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]; (an array of arrays)`

You'll have to adjust your server code to something that can serialize to that. An array of arrays probably work.