# How to pass array parameter from Code behind to javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to run a Javascript code within my ASP.NET project. In my ASP.NET project I have an array of information and i need to send it to javaScript to get handle information.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

My code is this:

Asp.net ARRAY´s:

```
foreach (string music in distinctMusic)
{
    musicList[i] = music;
    i++;
}

foreach (int musicDuration in distinctMusicDuration)
{
    musicDurationList[k] = musicDuration;
    k++;
}
```

JavaScript function:

```
function playNext(listMusic, musicDuration) {
    alert(listMusic[1]); //Test ...
}
```

That does not work. Help?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464498/pass-c-sharp-asp-net-array-to-javascript-array?rq=1

Comment: There are many similar questions in SO. Do some more research before posting your questions.

Comment: how are you calling the playNext function?

Comment: Is this WebForms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You are better off writing a service and calling it from script. If you want the quick easy dirty way, Jeff pointed you to a good writeup.

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(), "sleepTime", "playNext('" + musicList + "','" + musicDurationList + "');", true);

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the array to JSON and then de-serialize within Javascript. I think that will be the cleaner solution.

[ASP .NET JSON SERIALIZER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx)

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserialize-from-json-to-javascript-object) from JSON to javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) Method. It allows you to declare array name and array value (as comma-separated string)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to setup a property in your code behind and then you can access that property from your js.

```
public string[] musicList;

function playNext(listMusic, musicDuration) {
var musicList = <%=this.musicList%>;
}
```

I haven't tested this as I'm not at a good place to test it, but it should work in theory.