# Sending a list from cs to ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm pretty new to C# and am trying to rebuild something I build in PHP a few years back.

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

In the CS file I'm building a list of addresses (basically consists of name, address and coordinates) which I need in the ASCX file to build up a google map with some markers.

My code looks something like this:

```
var neighbors = new List<List<String>>();
var neighbor = new List<String>();

int x = 0;
String firstRowFirstColumnValue = "";

while (x < result.Result.Count) {
   GenericEntityData Resultrow = result.Result[x] as GenericEntityData;

    neighbor.Add(Resultrow .Properties[2].Value.ToString());
    neighbor.Add(Resultrow .Properties[3].Value.ToString());
    neighbor.Add(Resultrow .Properties[7].Value.ToString());

    neighbors.Add(neighbor);
    x++;
}
```

Now it seems like the list is populated the right way, but I can't figure out how to pass it to the ascx file. Any ideas?

Comment: By CS do you mean the code behind file?

Comment: If the code you provided is in a method of a class, create an instance of this class in the page_load event of the ascx codebehind and call the method on that instance to get your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is very similar:

[Pass C# ASP.NET array to Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464498/pass-c-sharp-asp-net-array-to-javascript-array)

I like zerkms answer the best. It has the most votes. What is missing from his answer is that you list (which is much like the array in the provided link) should be accessible through a public property at the class level. So put this right under your class declaration:

```
    public List<List<String>> Neighbors {get; set;}
```

and at after your while loop is done:

```
    Neighbors = neighbors;
```

In the ascx page you can put the list into javascript like this:

```
    <% var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); %>
    var jsVariable = <%= serializer.Serialize(Neighbors) %>;
```

unrelatedly: You may want consider making your neighbor (singular) List a custom class, rather than a List of Strings.

I might mention that things like this are a lot simpler using asp.NET MVC. That's no help to you here, but still worth saying.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I've indeed seen that it would be easier with a MVC, but I'm stuck making modifications in a existing application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `session` or `application` or make it as a `static` property, depends on your senario, if this list is unique for every user, you can set that on `session`, or if the list is unique for all users, you can set the list on `application` or create it as `static` property