# How to get list of objects from session in javascript ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox, asp.net-session

I have created checkboxes  dynamically from list of checkboxes and i saved this list into a session and want to get this List of checkboxes from session in checkbox's onChange event.
Here is the code.

```
    public static List <CheckBox> chklist = new List <CheckBox> ();
    void arrinit() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            //initializing list of checkboxes
            chklist.Add(new CheckBox());
        }
    }
    void show() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
            tRow.Cells.Add(cell4);
            ((IParserAccessor) cell4).AddParsedSubObject(chklist[i]);
            chklist[i].ID = "cbx_" + i.ToString();
            string a = "processChechBox('" + "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + chklist[i].ID + "'); return false;";
            chklist[i].Attributes.Add("onChange", a);
            chklist[i].Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        }
        Session["chk"] = chklist;
    }

    function processChechBox(id) {
        //here is the javascript function for checkbox onChange event
        debugger;
        var containerRef = document.getElementById(id);
        var data = document.getElementById(id);
        data.value = '1';
        data.checked = true;
        var a = '<%= Session["chk"]%>';
    }
```

`var a = '<%= Session["chk"]%>';`
this line is returning `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.CheckBox]` instead of list
`processChechBox(id)` this function is called on every check box checked.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
<%= Session["chk"]%>
```

Will write out the equivalent of

```
Session["chk"].ToString()
```

which obviously is not what you want here. What do what to accomplish with the 'var a' used here?

My guess is you really want something like this

```
<% var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); %>
var jsVariable = <%= serializer.Serialize(((List<CheckBox>)Session["chk"]).ToArray()) %>;
```

Credit to: [Pass C# ASP.NET array to Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464498/pass-c-sharp-asp-net-array-to-javascript-array)

Comment: I copied and paste your code and its giving me exception:
{"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}
and the inner exception is:
{"This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."}

Comment: If you change the app pool to use integrated that should go away, not sure why its required.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below approach and check what you got in console log.

```
function processChechBox(id) {
//here is the javascript function for checkbox onChange event
debugger;

var containerRef = document.getElementById(id);
var data = document.getElementById(id);
data.value = '1';
data.checked = true;

var list = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Session["chk"]) %>;
console.log(list);
```

}