# Asp.net Value Passing to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays, variables

I have worked about Google Maps Javascript API
I have an issue.

In my js code

```
        var RX1 = [];
        var RY1 = [];
        var RX2 = [];
        var RY2 = [];
        var i;
        try
        {
            for (i = 0; i < RRCount; i++)
            {
                RX1[i] = <%=ListBoxRX1.Items[i] %>;
                RY1[i] = <%=ListBoxRY1.Items[i] %>;
                RX2[i] = <%=ListBoxRX2.Items[i] %>;
                RY2[i] = <%=ListBoxRY2.Items[i] %>;
            }
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert("MSSQL 403 Hatası !! Forbidden.");
        }
```

in this code ListBoxRX1.Items[i] i variable error is "The name 'i' does not exist in the current context"

I did everything but I didn't have found. Please help!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The problem is, that the javascript code is executed on the client, whereas your ListBox code is executed on server side. That means, that at the point of accessing the ListBox items (on the server) `i` is not defined.

Comment: You might take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3465192/9487478

Comment: thx I will check this.

Comment: I finished this issue Thanks for all of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that "i" and the for loop are declared in the JavaScript, not in ASP.NET, and as a result they are not accessible to the code running on the server and the loop does not execute on the server.  You will need to have your loop run on the server, using something like this (assuming RRCount is a server side variable):

```
    var RX1 = [];
    var RY1 = [];
    var RX2 = [];
    var RY2 = [];
    var i;
    try
    {
        <% 
        for (int i = 0; i < RRCount; i++) 
        { 
        %>
            <%="RX1[" + i + "] = '" + ListBoxRX1.Items[i] + '";" %>
            <%="RY1[" + i + "] = '" + ListBoxRY1.Items[i] + '";" %>
            <%="RX2[" + i + "] = '" + ListBoxRX2.Items[i] + '";" %>
            <%="RY2[" + i + "] = '" + ListBoxRY2.Items[i] + '";" %>
        <% 
        }  
        %>
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("MSSQL 403 Hatası !! Forbidden.");
    }
```

Comment: I tried this thanks but it didn't work. Variables still get same error.

Comment: That's because "i" is still not declared. Use `for (int i = 0; i < RRCount; i++)`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Paul Pearce. I have fixed that from other Paul brother :))

Comment: Hi @SerkanKaya if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.  Thanks!